How to run ASP.NET Core 6.0 application in subdirectory?
I'm running an ASP.NET Core 6 app in a subdirectory myapp. This used to work fine in the ASP.NET Core 5 MVC version, but now when I have a form, using Html.BeginForm(), it posts to the root url instead of under myapp.
I've tried app.UsePathBase("myapp"), but this seems to do exactly nothing. And conveniently enough the mechanisms how to deal with this change about every 3 years, so good luck searching for a solution.
Edit: funnily enough the generated html is <form action="/myapp/MyController" method="post">, so that looks correct?

Ok, I found the problem, it was my own fault, but kinda unexpected due to a change in what HttpRequest.Path returns in ASP.NET Core. In my controller POST method, I did a redirect to the GET method, to turn the POST values into url parameters. And in this redirect I used HttpRequest.Path, as I did in ASP.NET MVC 5. But apparently this used to contain the PathBase, but no longer does in ASP.NET Core! What an unpleasant change of definition, it cost me all day to find this, because I'm not very fluent in trouble shooting ASP.
I eventually figured I need to log what ASP is doing, and turning on the logging is what pointed me to the incorrect redirect. I changed the "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning" level to "Information" in appsettings.json and changed stdoutLogEnabled to "true" in Web.config to log what's happening.
So in the end I didn't need to call app.UsePathBase(), because it seems to be handled automatically already.
